# Integrate custom device into Google Home

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, led, google-home

My idea is to have single addressable RGBW LED strips in all my rooms. For the sake of practice and interest, I do not simply want to by some controller, I want to start this project with some custom self-build infrastructure, consisting of some Arduinos and/or raspberry pis. My initial idea was to just setup a simple local server on a raspberry (which controls the arduinos connected to the LEDs) and build myself an app to control the lightning. That part is clear to me and should not be a problem, but I thought it might be a plus to integrate my devices directly to Google Home so I do not need any extra app.
I read through the [Smart Home Platform](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) but things are not 100% clear to me. I read things about requirements like public Oauth2 Server. I was wondering, if it is possible to get this working without setting up any server which has to be reached publicly, because otherwise I won't waste time on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control your room devices from a smartphone and are satisfied with local operation from few meters away than you should consider BLE on phone and devices.

Obviously, you would need to write your own app, but luckily with BLE you can use publicly available apps such as LightBlu for the dev phase and maybe even for later use (I have not looked into that lately).

Comment: I'm not sure if BLE is sufficient since I would like to control LEDs from anywhere in my flat, so generally a local network is sufficient and there are indeed many options to make this working, the initial question is not how to control them but if it is possible to integrate them into Google Home without setting up any own servers which needs to be publicly available

Comment: Yeah I agree with @mmm BLE is not a good option. Did you manage to work something out on the Google Home integration?